# How to format and print a String[] array and int[][] array into a table together

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeBook 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting program\n\n");
        String[] STUDENT_NAMES = new String[] {"Adams", "Baker", "Campbell", "Dewey", "East"};
        int[][] STUDENT_GRADES = new int[5][3];
        
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                STUDENT_GRADES[i][j] = 5;
            }
        }
        
        printArray(STUDENT_NAMES);
        print2DArray(STUDENT_GRADES);   
        
    } //end main
        
    public static void printArray(String[] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    
    public static void print2DArray(int arr[][])
    {
        for(int row = 0; row<arr.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<arr[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.println(arr[row][col] + " ");
            }
        }

    }
    
} //end class
```

This assignment for class has me creating a Gradebook for students using a String[] for names, and int[][] for grades. The Gradebook displays the students name with their exam grades in the corresponding row. It specifies 5 names to be loaded in the String[], and the int[][] to be of size [5][3]. The final output of the program should look like this:

Adams       75 75

Baker       100 75

Campbell    84 75

Dewey       80 75

East        50 75

I am having trouble figuring out how to print both String[] and int[][] together, with the names being formatted as shown to the left.

In my program I loaded the int[][] with 5's as a test placeholder. I thought of inputting the specific grades when I declared int[][] as a variable, but since its length is [5][3], I thought the String[] should be in int[i][0]

Comment: Did your assignment state that you should use "a String[] for names, and int[][] for grades"? Because there are definitely better solutions.

Comment: Yeah our professor wants us using those specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what is difficult for you is the printing together, and you can do it this way:

```
public static void printArray(String[] names,int [][] grades)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[i]+" "+ Arrays.toString(grades[i]).replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").trim());
        }
    }
```

the output:

```
Adams 5 5 5
Baker 5 5 5
Campbell 5 5 5
Dewey 5 5 5
East 5 5 5
```